# How can I transform "email@domain.com" to "em***@domain.com"?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, gsub

I want to transform emails only showing the first two characters and substitute the rest of them with '*' and keep the '@domain.com' as it is, how can I do it

I already have this code that works as expected but I would like to have a reduced way to do it, I don't know if there is a way to do it with `gsub` method and pass some ranges, any help will be appreciated

```rb
email = 'email@domain.com'
splitted_email = email.partition('@')
splitted_email.first[2...email.size-2]
splitted_email[0] = splitted_email.first[0...2] + ('*' *(splitted_email.first.size-2))
splitted_email.join

=> em***@domain.com
```

Comment: Try `email.gsub(/(\G(?!\A)|(?<=\A[^@]{2}))[^@]/, '\1*')`, see https://regex101.com/r/8BzXfC/1

Comment: What if the local part has less than 5 characters?

Comment: If you want me to explain the above `gsub` I will add to the answer.

Comment: What is the expected output for `foo@domain.com`? `fo***@domain.com` or `fo*@domain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex for this. A more or less readable one is

```
.gsub(/(?<=\A[^@]{2})[^@]*/) { |m| "*" * m.length }
```

What it does is matches

- `(?<=\A[^@]{2})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with:

  - `\A` - string start
  - `[^@]{2}` - two chars other than `@`
- `[^@]+` - any 1+ chars other than `@`.

The replacement is the block where we can manipulate the match: the `*` char is repeated the same number of times as the length of the match value.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/0a13Ez):

```
email = 'email@domain.com'
p email.gsub(/(?<=\A[^@]{2})[^@]+/) { |m| "*" * m.length }
# => "em***@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email.gsub(/(^.{2})[^@]*(@.*)$/,'\1***\2')
```

But i does not work with only one letter in front of @.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Object.html#method-i-then):

```
email.split('@').then { |a, b| a[0..-4] + '*' * 3 + '@' + b }
```

or

```
email.partition('@').then { |a, b, c| a[0..-4]+ '*' * 3 + b + c }
```

For the following cases it returns

```
email = 'email@domain.com' #=> "em***@domain.com"
email = 'emai@domain.com'  #=> "e***@domain.com"
email = 'ema@domain.com'   #=> "***@domain.com"
email = 'e@domain.com'     #=> "***@domain.com"
```

But I don't know how you intend to manage when *local-part* is smaller than 4 chars.